# How to create Zip-File from Raw-Data from Http-Request?

Tags: java, zip

I'am trying to create a Zip-File from the Raw-String (like when you open a Zip-file with an editor) I get from an API.
I've tried using the Zip-API from Java 8, but I get an "java.util.zip.ZipException: too many length or distance symbols"-Error.

```
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(bis);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ArchiveTest.zip");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);

        ZipEntry currentEntry;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        while ((currentEntry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(currentEntry.getName());
            zos.putNextEntry(newEntry);
            int length;
            while ((length = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            zos.closeEntry();                   
        }

        zos.close();
```

My guess is that Java cannot process the unknown Characters and changes them, but how can I change that behaviour?

Thanks for any replies!

Comment: You should always give a character encoding to `String.getBytes()` since likely the encoding delivered is not the local system encoding, e.g. `s.getBytes("UTF-8")`
BTW: I don't get your code: you receive a zip file, decode it with `ZipInputStream` and write it again with `ZipOutputStream`. Why not simply write the `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get bytes from a `String` one should (always) specify an encoding, like `String s = "äüö"; byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8");` or even better `...; byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Here you should use following (if website charset is "UTF-8"):

```
InputStream bis = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess it worked, since I am getting a different Error now.
`java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type` So is the received Zip-Stream faulty?

Edit: To adress your point in your comment above: I want to create a Zip-File with the content of the received Http-Response. Is there a more elegant way of doing this? Because what I found is, that ZipOutputStream is for creating Zip-Files and ZipInputStream is for reading Zip-Files.

Comment: Is your "received HTTP-Response" a zip-file or is it anything else (HTML, PDF, ...)? If it's not a zip-file you cannot unzip it with `ZipInputStream`.

Comment: It is a Zip-File in Text-Form. As if you'd open it with notepad. Starts with "PK...". I just want to take that and save it as a Zip-File.

Comment: You'd better save it directly from your source and check, if it is a valid ZIP file.
"ZIP-File in text-form"? A zip file is always binary, your texteditor tries to interpret the contents and prints out rubbish, since not interpretable. You did not specify your source in the question. Why is there a String `s` that contains the "zip-file"`???

Comment: "You'd better save it directly from your source [...]" - How do I do that? 
I guess I'm beginning to understand where the problem is. I do an Unirest Request and the response body is stored in the String s. Can I change 'HttpResponse<String>' to 'HttpResponse<Byte>' in the Unirest Request?

Comment: From the documentation of unirest:
"`Requests are made when as[Type]() is invoked, possible types include Json, Binary, String, Object.`". You should use `asBinary()`, which is not described in the Javadoc, so you could try `asFile()` or `asFileAsync()`.